# how to change one column and add other columns in a row by awk

Tags: shell-script, awk

I have a file MDD.TXT with following records.
file : MDD.TXT

```
0|ABC|055309|20120929053309|11965150   
0|ABC|061434|20120929063434|11155537  
0|ABC|070228|20120929073228|11965150  
0|ABC|082213|20120929583213|11965150  
0|ABC|083950|20120929983950|11965150  
0|ABC|084112|20120929083112|11965150
```

Now I want to replace the second column with "XYZ" and want to add two column filename and "success" in all record. the desired output should be following:

```
0|XYZ|055309|20120929053309|11965150|MDD.TXT|SUCCESS
0|XYZ|061434|20120929063434|11155537|MDD.TXT|SUCCESS
0|XYZ|070228|20120929073228|11965150|MDD.TXT|SUCCESS
0|XYZ|082213|20120929583213|11965150|MDD.TXT|SUCCESS
0|XYZ|083950|20120929983950|11965150|MDD.TXT|SUCCESS
0|XYZ|084112|20120929083112|11965150|MDD.TXT|SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try following `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "|" } { $2 = "XYZ"; $6 = ARGV[1]; $7 = "SUCCESS";} 1' MDD.TXT
```

or:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "|" } { $2 = "XYZ"; print $0 OFS ARGV[1] OFS "SUCCESS"; }' MDD.TXT
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `sed` as well

```
$ sed -e 's/\bABC\b/XYZ/g' -e 's/$/|MDD.TXT|SUCCESS/g' MDD.TXT
```

To make the modification to the file directly

```
$ sed -i -e 's/\bABC\b/XYZ/g' -e 's/$/|MDD.TXT|SUCCESS/g' MDD.TXT
```

To keep the original file and redirect the wanted output to other

```
$ sed -e 's/\bABC\b/XYZ/g' -e 's/$/|MDD.TXT|SUCCESS/g' MDD.TXT >> MDD_MODIFFIED.TXT
```

Comment: Why are you escaping pipes when you are using BRE ?

Comment: @User112638726 Thanks for the observation

Answer (score 4):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="|"} {$2="XYZ"; $0=$0"|"FILENAME"|SUCCESS"}1' mdd.txt
```

Where:

- The `BEGIN{}` is executed only at the beginning, not for every line.
- `OFS=FS="|"` sets the input and output field separator to `|`.
- `$2="XYZ"` sets the second field to `XYZ`
- `$0=...` appends to the whole line the `FILENAME` (from `awk`s internal variables) and `SUCCESS` as a string.

Answer (score 2):

This is the same idea as the existing `awk` answers but a little more concise:

```
awk -F'|' -vOFS="|" '{$2="XYZ"; print $0,"MDD.TXT","SUCCESS"}' MDD.TXT
```

To make it add the file name automatically (for any file name), use:

```
awk -F'|' -vOFS="|" '{$2="XYZ"; print $0,ARGV[1],"SUCCESS"}' MDD.TXT
```

The `-F` sets the input record separator and the `-vOFS` sets the `OFS` variable, the output record separator. Then, we set the second field to `XYZ` and print the line (`$0`), the file name (`ARGV[1]`) and `SUCCESS`.

Note that in your example, you have trailing whitespace on each line, so running any of the proposed solutions will result in:

```
$ awk -F'|' -vOFS="|" '{$2="XYZ"; print $0,ARGV[1],"SUCCESS"}' MDD.TXT 
0|XYZ|055309|20120929053309|11965150   |MDD.TXT|SUCCESS
0|XYZ|061434|20120929063434|11155537  |MDD.TXT|SUCCESS
0|XYZ|070228|20120929073228|11965150  |MDD.TXT|SUCCESS
0|XYZ|082213|20120929583213|11965150  |MDD.TXT|SUCCESS
0|XYZ|083950|20120929983950|11965150  |MDD.TXT|SUCCESS
0|XYZ|084112|20120929083112|11965150|MDD.TXT|SUCCESS
```

To avoid that, you could set the input field separator to `|` **or** space:

```
$ awk -F' |' -vOFS="|" '{$2="XYZ"; print $0,ARGV[1],"SUCCESS"}' MDD.TXT 
0|ABC|055309|20120929053309|11965150|XYZ|||MDD.TXT|SUCCESS
0|ABC|061434|20120929063434|11155537|XYZ||MDD.TXT|SUCCESS
0|ABC|070228|20120929073228|11965150|XYZ||MDD.TXT|SUCCESS
0|ABC|082213|20120929583213|11965150|XYZ||MDD.TXT|SUCCESS
0|ABC|083950|20120929983950|11965150|XYZ||MDD.TXT|SUCCESS
0|ABC|084112|20120929083112|11965150|XYZ|MDD.TXT|SUCCESS
```

Or, you could just remove the trailing whitespace before parsing the file:

```
sed 's/\s*$//' MDD.TXT | 
    awk -F' |' -vOFS="|" '{$2="XYZ"; print $0,"MDD.TXT|SUCCESS"}'
```